# Using flex to scroll one div and not another?

Tags: html, css, scroll, flexbox

On a kendo window I have two divs inside a main div container, the main content and a footer bar. I want to be able to scroll the main content panel while the footer does not scroll.

I have been playing with this for a little while using flex-grow and htmls own overscroll property but I cannot get one to move without the other. Any help would be appreciated :)

I can provide more info as required.

This represents the basic example of what I've done so far:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  overflow: auto;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.main {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: green;
}

.footer {
  flex-grow: 0;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="main"><p> Main content </p> </div>
  <div class="footer"> <p> Footer bar </p> </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the appropriate edit.

Comment: It's good practice and easier to understand if you keep your styles separate from your markup. Also, providing a minimal, working example of your specific problem will be helpful to those who are trying to help you. You can do this with the help of a stack snippet - I have put your code into one for you.

Comment: Thanks Billy. Unfortunately I dont think I can share the specifics of my code because its a bug I've encountered at work, o just trying to find a basic fix without going into specifics. The data itself inside the divs shouldnt be relevant to the solution.

Comment: You just need the minimal code that replicates the issue. If you need some content to replicate it then use some dummy content - such as [lorem ipsum](http://www.lipsum.com)

Comment: How can I use the overscroll in the code snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}



.Main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
}

.Header {
  height: auto; /* or height: Npx;, where N is a positive number */
  background: #84dcc6;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.Footer {
  flex: 1;
  background: #ffa69e;
  overflow-y: auto;

}
```

```html
<main class="Main">
  <header class="Header">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident adipisci cum nisi dignissimos quas molestiae, ullam labore iste quisquam nobis nam eius quos ducimus. Deserunt, molestias veniam tempore corrupti eveniet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident adipisci cum nisi dignissimos quas molestiae, ullam labore iste quisquam nobis nam eius quos ducimus. Deserunt, molestias veniam tempore corrupti eveniet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident adipisci cum nisi dignissimos quas molestiae, ullam labore iste quisquam nobis nam eius quos ducimus. Deserunt, molestias veniam tempore corrupti eveniet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident adipisci cum nisi dignissimos quas molestiae, ullam labore iste quisquam nobis nam eius quos ducimus. Deserunt, molestias veniam tempore corrupti eveniet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident adipisci cum nisi dignissimos quas molestiae, ullam labore iste quisquam nobis nam eius quos ducimus. Deserunt, molestias veniam tempore corrupti eveniet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident adipisci cum nisi dignissimos quas molestiae, ullam labore iste quisquam nobis nam eius quos ducimus. Deserunt, molestias veniam tempore corrupti eveniet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident adipisci cum nisi dignissimos quas molestiae, ullam labore iste quisquam nobis nam eius quos ducimus. Deserunt, molestias veniam tempore corrupti eveniet.</header>
  <footer class="Footer">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident adipisci cum nisi dignissimos quas molestiae, ullam labore iste quisquam nobis nam eius quos ducimus. Deserunt, molestias veniam tempore corrupti eveniet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident adipisci cum nisi dignissimos quas molestiae, ullam labore iste quisquam nobis nam eius quos ducimus. Deserunt, molestias veniam tempore corrupti eveniet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident adipisci cum nisi dignissimos quas molestiae, ullam labore iste quisquam nobis nam eius quos ducimus. Deserunt, molestias veniam tempore corrupti eveniet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident adipisci cum nisi dignissimos quas molestiae, ullam labore iste quisquam nobis nam eius quos ducimus. Deserunt, molestias veniam tempore corrupti eveniet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident adipisci cum nisi dignissimos quas molestiae, ullam labore iste quisquam nobis nam eius quos ducimus. Deserunt, molestias veniam tempore corrupti eveniet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident adipisci cum nisi dignissimos quas molestiae, ullam labore iste quisquam nobis nam eius quos ducimus. Deserunt, molestias veniam tempore corrupti eveniet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident adipisci cum nisi dignissimos quas molestiae, ullam labore iste quisquam nobis nam eius quos ducimus. Deserunt, molestias veniam tempore corrupti eveniet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident adipisci cum nisi dignissimos quas molestiae, ullam labore iste quisquam nobis nam eius quos ducimus. Deserunt, molestias veniam tempore corrupti eveniet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident adipisci cum nisi dignissimos quas molestiae, ullam labore iste quisquam nobis nam eius quos ducimus. Deserunt, molestias veniam tempore corrupti eveniet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident adipisci cum nisi dignissimos quas molestiae, ullam labore iste quisquam nobis nam eius quos ducimus. Deserunt, molestias veniam tempore corrupti eveniet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident adipisci cum nisi dignissimos quas molestiae, ullam labore iste quisquam nobis nam eius quos ducimus. Deserunt, molestias veniam tempore corrupti eveniet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident adipisci cum nisi dignissimos quas molestiae, ullam labore iste quisquam nobis nam eius quos ducimus. Deserunt, molestias veniam tempore corrupti eveniet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident adipisci cum nisi dignissimos quas molestiae, ullam labore iste quisquam nobis nam eius quos ducimus. Deserunt, molestias veniam tempore corrupti eveniet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident adipisci cum nisi dignissimos quas molestiae, ullam labore iste quisquam nobis nam eius quos ducimus. Deserunt, molestias veniam tempore corrupti eveniet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident adipisci cum nisi dignissimos quas molestiae, ullam labore iste quisquam nobis nam eius quos ducimus. Deserunt, molestias veniam tempore corrupti eveniet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident adipisci cum nisi dignissimos quas molestiae, ullam labore iste quisquam nobis nam eius quos ducimus. Deserunt, molestias veniam tempore corrupti eveniet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident adipisci cum nisi dignissimos quas molestiae, ullam labore iste quisquam nobis nam eius quos ducimus. Deserunt, molestias veniam tempore corrupti eveniet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident adipisci cum nisi dignissimos quas molestiae, ullam labore iste quisquam nobis nam eius quos ducimus. Deserunt, molestias veniam tempore corrupti eveniet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident adipisci cum nisi dignissimos quas molestiae, ullam labore iste quisquam nobis nam eius quos ducimus. Deserunt, molestias veniam tempore corrupti eveniet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident adipisci cum nisi dignissimos quas molestiae, ullam labore iste quisquam nobis nam eius quos ducimus. Deserunt, molestias veniam tempore corrupti eveniet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident adipisci cum nisi dignissimos quas molestiae, ullam labore iste quisquam nobis nam eius quos ducimus. Deserunt, molestias veniam tempore corrupti eveniet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident adipisci cum nisi dignissimos quas molestiae, ullam labore iste quisquam nobis nam eius quos ducimus. Deserunt, molestias veniam tempore corrupti eveniet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident adipisci cum nisi dignissimos quas molestiae, ullam labore iste quisquam nobis nam eius quos ducimus. Deserunt, molestias veniam tempore corrupti eveniet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident adipisci cum nisi dignissimos quas molestiae, ullam labore iste quisquam nobis nam eius quos ducimus. Deserunt, molestias veniam tempore corrupti eveniet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident adipisci cum nisi dignissimos quas molestiae, ullam labore iste quisquam nobis nam eius quos ducimus. Deserunt, molestias veniam tempore corrupti eveniet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident adipisci cum nisi dignissimos quas molestiae, ullam labore iste quisquam nobis nam eius quos ducimus. Deserunt, molestias veniam tempore corrupti eveniet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident adipisci cum nisi dignissimos quas molestiae, ullam labore iste quisquam nobis nam eius quos ducimus. Deserunt, molestias veniam tempore corrupti eveniet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident adipisci cum nisi dignissimos quas molestiae, ullam labore iste quisquam nobis nam eius quos ducimus. Deserunt, molestias veniam tempore corrupti eveniet.
  </footer>
</main>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Not entirely right, but it helped me and my coworker reach the solution. This thread can now be closed.